# Visual Studio - Persist Pinned Windows?

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, tabs

Is there anyway to persist pinned windows between visual studio closures?

At the moment, if you pin a window, when you close visual studio and open it back up again, the pinned status of said window has been reset and it is lumped in with all the other windows again.

Comment: @sethflowers i guess im unlucky then lol

Comment: Not unlucky.  Persistence of pinned windows is pretty random for me.

Comment: Is it any window, or just specific windows? I tried pinning two different windows I don't normally have open or pinned, and closing and opening VS2012 a couple of times.

Comment: its just normal file windows. for some reason the pinned status doesn't persist across sessions

Comment: Anyone ever find a solution to this? The "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well" answer did not work for me.

Comment: No idea still.  I am now using vs 2008 and it is also awful

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try to enable this setting
(if it's currently unchecked):

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Check "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well"`

This solved me the same problem.

Comment: This should be on by default! That whole thing was driving me nuts and randomly losing my pins every so often. Thank you!

Comment: This works for unpinned windows as well (not sure what cleared it).

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me (using VS 2017). Apparently it's on the roadmap: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/510528/pinned-tabs-should-be-pinned-after-relaunch.html

Answer (score 11):

I hope this is not too late. I was having similar issues in VS 2013.
I have found that pinned tabs were lost after restarting and then running the Solution, when we have the plugin, **Productivity Power Tools installed**.

I removed it and now the pinned tabs are not lost since then.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issues in VS 2013 and the Web Essentials Update 3 extension. After I disabled it it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer solved it for me in previous versions, but in VS2017, also ensure you don't have "lightweight solution load" enabled.

To disable, right-click the solution in Solution explorer, then choose "Disable Lightweight Solution Load" if it's available (probably right down the bottom of the menu).

My guess is when the pin tabs attempt to be restored during VS startup, if the project hasn't been loaded yet, it can't pin them.

(I also posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47202448/2738122))