# VS2012 Productivity Power Tools Pinned Tabs close on run

Tags: visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

If I open a saved project with pinned tabs restored from my last session, when I next run my solution the pinned tabs become unpinned. Is there a way to turn this behavior off? I pinned them for a reason and it is becoming quite frustrating as the solution grows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/34242a45-1758-4fb7-aa94-16ed1f539d7d/)

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows` and make sure "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well" is checked.

Comment: Still true for Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I have this option selected but the pinned tabs still become unpinned and I have to reopen them all after restarting VS. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer solved it for me in previous versions, but in VS2017, also ensure you don't have "lightweight solution load" enabled.

To disable, right-click the solution in Solution explorer, then choose "Disable Lightweight Solution Load" if it's available (probably right down the bottom of the menu).

My guess is when the pin tabs attempt to be restored during VS startup, if the project hasn't been loaded yet, it can't pin them.