# Visual Studio 2012 detach Design View window

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to "float" the Design view window out the bottom toolbar like it's possible with other windows? I want to place it on a second monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Design View Windows can be "pinned" and "unpinned" as the other windows and moved to a second monitor. Use this little pin window on the tab of the window banner. See a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571452/visual-studio-persist-pinned-windows).

[image]

Comment: I think I meant to detach the Design view alone, not everything.

Comment: Using the pin, I can move the Design view to the second monitor and leav all the other views on the first one.

Comment: He cannot. Even in VS 2013. Design pane is a part of a tab.

Comment: There is a detailed Microsoft description [Customizing window layouts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Design View cannot be float separately as it is **bound to source code**.

But **small trick** can be applied as i am using it.

Open your **solution file twice**(**two visual studio will be opened**).

Put one solution in **one screen**(in this case **design view**) and other solution(**code view**) on **other screen**.

After **changing made** in **Source**, save it and switch to Design solution, it will **prompt to load the change**, say yes the **latest change save will be reflected in Design** also.

[image]

Comment: OK. If so then there might not be solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, I don't think you could *float* your design like that.

However, what you could perhaps do is:

- Pop out file from the visual studio tab
- Split the Source and Design view vertically (|)
- Resize the window to cover both of your monitors.
- One monitor will have your source, another design.

E.g.

[image]

This way when you select some line in *XAML/ASPX* you see focus in *Design view*

Comment: The deal with this question is when you select some line in XAML you see focus in Design view.

Comment: Your window position and sizing are not maintained, so every time you re-open the file, you have to repeat this procedure. :-(